How to Refresh Data in Dataverse from Excel in Power Apps
I uploaded data to Dataverse in Power Apps from Excel. After making edits to the Excel file, I want to refresh the data in Dataverse to reflect those changes. However, when I go to the table and click "Edit," I see a refresh button, but it doesn't seem to do anything. How can I refresh the data in Dataverse to reflect the changes made in the Excel file?

While importing the excel file to dataverse, if the connection is not live than changes won't automatically reflect inside the dataverse. Just re-import again the excel-file or you can use power Query as well.

Hmm yeah. I’m curious how to automate it so it updates when changes are made to the excel. When you say use power query, does that mean in excel? Or is that somewhere in power apps
